# Error in installing Tensorflow on Mac

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

I installed Tensorflow on my macOS Sierra using `pip install tensorflow`. 
Im getting the following error:

`OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not 
permitted:'/var/folders/zn/l9gmn4613677f6mlrh6prtb00000gn/T/pip-xv3AU6-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy-1.8.0rc1-py2.7.egg-info'`

Is there anyway to resolve this?

Comment: Have you tried running sudo pip install tensorflow? or sudo pip uninstall numpy? Whatever you're trying to do

Comment: I tried the command with sudo but the same error is coming up.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to install tensorflow with virtual env as described here: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_mac. I encountered some conflict and access write issues, too. With virtual env everything worked well.

Additionally, so you could install the GPU and the CPU version of tensorflow in parallel and use them both, depending on the context. For example, the GPU version made problems with some debugging environment, for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use Python EasyInstall, is super easy:
sudo easy_install pip